# List of tooltip-trigger event names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Angular-Ui bootstrap's tooltip-trigger, which the documentation (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) describes as

> `tooltip-trigger`: What should trigger a show of the tooltip? Supports a space separated list of event names. Note: this attribute is no longer observable.

Is there a list of all implemented event names somewhere?

Comment: i can see a section about `triggers` there, just few lines below, is there anything else you are looking for?

Comment: yes, I seem have been searching on the wrong keyword...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can read about that few lines below

> Triggers
>
> The following show triggers are supported out of the box, along with
> their provided hide triggers:
>
> mouseenter: mouseleave
>
> click: click
>
> focus: blur
>
> none: ``
>
> For any non-supported value, the trigger will be used to both show and hide
> the tooltip. Using the 'none' trigger will disable the internal
> trigger(s), one can then use the tooltip-is-open attribute exclusively
> to show and hide the tooltip.